# Reset files in Git which show as modified but have no changes according to “git diff”

Tags: performance, bash, shell, git

This *seems* to be working but also is quite horrendously slow and seems a little hacky to me.

```
IFS=$'\n'

for currentFile in $(git status | grep "modified:" | cut -c 14-)
do
    gitDiff=$(git diff "$currentFile")
    gitDiffStr="[$gitDiff]"
    if [ "$gitDiffStr" == "[]" ]
    then
        echo match
        echo git checkout "$currentFile"
        git checkout "$currentFile"
    fi
done
```

Comment: what's wrong with `git checkout -- .`?

Comment: That would reset all of the files. I only wanted to reset the ones that show as changed but have no changes according to `git diff`. I'd like to maintain the ones that have genuine changes. This is definitely not explained well enough in my post, though.

Comment: Same question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48688292/7552

Comment: I wonder if you really need to parse the `git status` output; does `git diff --name-only` list such files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The slowness

The slowness most probably comes from executing multiple `git diff` commands.
A faster way *might* be using a programming language with a Git library that would let you run a single `git diff` command,
and iterate over the entries of the diff to find the empty ones.

#### The hacky part

This is hacky:

```
git status | grep "modified:" | cut -c 14-
```

The output of the `git status` is not API,
and may also be subject to aliases and user settings.
It's not safe to use.
When parsing the output of Git commands,
look for a `--porcelain` option to make it safe.

Another hacky part is changing the value of `IFS`.
It's not a huge problem,
but it's good to minimize the scope of the change,
typically by using it in the form of `IFS=... cmd`,
which would limit the effect of the change to the execution of the `cmd` command.

Lastly, some minor style issues:

- The `$gitDiffStr` variable is pointless, you can simply inline it.
- The `==` operator within a `[ ... ]` is undocumented. Use `=` instead.

#### Alternative implementation

Applying the above suggestions, this is less hacky, and probably just as slow:

```
git status --porcelain -z | grep -z '^ M' | while IFS= read -r -d '' path0; do
    path=${path0:3}
    gitDiff=$(git diff "$path")
    if [ "$gitDiff" = "" ]; then
        echo git checkout "$currentFile"
        git checkout "$currentFile"
    fi
done
```